# Issue with numbers calculating in C++ outfile

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to create a text file output that shows the results and breakdown of district voting from a data file.  I am having issues getting the proper numbers to calculate.  The voting document (votes.dat) only contains two characters per line "District and Y/N".  I am not sure why I keep coming up with numbers like 4317448 and 2600960 when there are only a handful of entries (less than 10).

```
#include <string>   
string using namespace std
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

int main()

{

ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;
char vote;
int district;
int overallTotal;
int yesTotal;
int noTotal;
int d1Yesvotes;
int d1Novotes;
int d2Yesvotes;
int d2Novotes;
int d3Yesvotes;
int d3Novotes;


//open file

 infile.open("votes.dat");

infile>>district>>vote;


//if statement for 'yes' and 'no' votes, containing nested if statements



if (district=='1')
    {        
        if(vote=='Y') 
        {
            yesTotal+1;
            d1Yesvotes+1;
            overallTotal+1; }

    else if(vote=='N')
    { 
        noTotal+1;
            d1Novotes+1;
            overallTotal+1; }
     }

    else
if (district=='2')
    {        
        if(vote=='Y') 
        {yesTotal+1;
            d2Yesvotes+1;
            overallTotal+1;}

    else if(vote=='N')
    { noTotal+1;
            d2Novotes+1;
            overallTotal+1;}
       }
      else
if (district=='3')
    {        
        if(vote=='Y') 
        {yesTotal+1;
            d3Yesvotes+1;
            overallTotal+1;}

    else if(vote=='N')
    { noTotal+1;
            d3Novotes+1;
            overallTotal+1;}

       }


outfile.open("votingresults.txt"); 
outfile<<endl<<"Number of Overall votes: "<<overallTotal;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of Yes votes: "<<yesTotal;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of No votes: "<<noTotal;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 1 Yes Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 1 No Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 2 Yes Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 2 No Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 3 Yes Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 3 No Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;




//close files

infile.close();
    outfile.close();


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.
- It only reads 1 line of the code, then quits
- You are not incrementing your variables properly

```
yesTotal+1;
```

Will effectively just calculate yesTotal + 1, but not store iy anywhere.
You need to do one of the following

```
yesTotal=yesTotal+1;
yesTotal++; // This does the same thing
```

Here is a fixed version of your code

```
#include <string>   
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

int main()

{

ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;
char vote;
int district;
int overallTotal=0;
int yesTotal=0;
int noTotal=0;
int d1Yesvotes=0;
int d1Novotes=0;
int d2Yesvotes=0;
int d2Novotes=0;
int d3Yesvotes=0;
int d3Novotes=0;


//open file

infile.open("votes.dat");


//if statement for 'yes' and 'no' votes, containing nested if statements
string line;
if (!infile.is_open()) {
  cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
  return 0;
}

while (getline(infile, line)) {
  cout << line << endl;
  if (line.size() < 2)
    continue;
  district=line[0];
  vote=line[1];
  if (district=='1')
  {        
    if(vote=='Y') 
    {
      yesTotal++;
      d1Yesvotes++;
      overallTotal++;
    }

    else if(vote=='N')
    { 
      noTotal++;
      d1Novotes++;
      overallTotal++;
    }
  }

  else if (district=='2')
  {        
    if(vote=='Y') 
    {
      yesTotal++;
      d2Yesvotes++;
      overallTotal++;
    }

    else if(vote=='N')
    {
      noTotal++;
      d2Novotes++;
      overallTotal++;
    }
  }
  else if (district=='3')
  {        
    if(vote=='Y') {
      yesTotal++;
      d3Yesvotes++;
      overallTotal++;
    }

    else if(vote=='N')
    {
      noTotal++;
      d3Novotes++;
      overallTotal++;
    }
  }
}


outfile.open("votingresults.txt"); 
outfile<<endl<<"Number of Overall votes: "<<overallTotal;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of Yes votes: "<<yesTotal;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of No votes: "<<noTotal;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 1 Yes Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 1 No Votes: "<<d1Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 2 Yes Votes: "<<d2Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 2 No Votes: "<<d2Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl;
outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 3 Yes Votes: "<<d3Yesvotes;
    outfile<<endl<<"Number of District 3 No Votes: "<<d3Yesvotes;




//close files

infile.close();
outfile.close();


return 0;

}
```

I also changed the output variables to use the correct ones, as your example was writing d1YesVotes and d1NoVotes for all 3 districts.

Comment: Minor improvement: You could save half the code by refactoring out stuff. if (vote == 'Y') { yestotal++, overalltotal++ if (district=='1') D1Yesvotes++....

Comment: This is what I have atm: https://pastebin.com/w8Pu7tFD

It's still not outputting the proper text file.  Everything is still showing up as zeros in the votingresults.txt

Comment: i fixed it.  the issue was my data file has a space between the district and the vote.  haha.  thank you for the help!

Comment: Nice.
You can mark my answer as the accepted answer by pressing the gray checker under the votes if you feel it was what was needed. :-)